# How do you use ExportFactory<T>

Tags: c#, mef

I am new to MEF and experimenting with ExportFactory.  Can I use ExportFactory to create a list based on user insertion of objects?  A sample would be something similar to what is shown below.  I am probably not understanding the use of ExportFactory because during runtime I get an error shown below during composition.

> 1) No valid exports were found that match the constraint
>   '((exportDefinition.ContractName ==
>   "System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory(CommonLibrary.IFoo)")
>   AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity")
>   AndAlso
>   "System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory(CommonLibrary.IFoo)".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))',
>   invalid exports may have been rejected.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test mytest = new Test();
    }
}

public class Test : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [Import]
    private ExportFactory<IFoo> FooFactory { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
        CreateComponent("Amp");
        CreateComponent("Passive");
    }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        int i = 0;
    }

    public void CreateComponent(string name)
    {
        var componentExport = FooFactory.CreateExport();
        var comp = componentExport.Value;
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    double Name { get; set; }
}

[ExportMetadata("CompType", "Foo1")]
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public double Name { get; set; }
    public Foo1()
    {

    }
}

[ExportMetadata("CompType", "Foo2")]
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public double Name { get; set; }
    public Foo2()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually show the imports on your test class, so it's difficult to tell what is wrong with them. Please edit your question.

Comment: I just edited the previous source to now show the Import

Answer (score 13):

The problem appears to be that you expect to import a single `ExportFactory<IFoo>`, but you have exported two different `IFoo` implementations. In your example, MEF wouldn't be able to decide between both implementations.

You probably want to import multiple factories including metadata like this:

```
[ImportMany]
private IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IFoo,IFooMeta>> FooFactories 
{ 
    get;
    set;
}
```

where `IFooMeta` would be declared like this:

```
public interface IFooMeta
{
    string CompType { get; }
}
```

and then you could implement `CreateComponent` like this:

```
public IFoo CreateComponent(string name, string compType)
{
    var matchingFactory = FooFactories.FirstOrDefault(
        x => x.Metadata.CompType == compType);
    if (matchingFactory == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format("'{0}' is not a known compType", compType),
            "compType");
    }
    else
    {
        IFoo foo = matchingFactory.CreateExport().Value;
        foo.Name = name;
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still having problems with using ExportFactory. Do I need to change [Import] to [ImportMany]? I was getting an error when the container was created using [Import]. When I changed it to [ImportMany] the container is constructed but now the CreateComponent method says there is no "Foo1".

Comment: I indeed intended to write `[ImportMany]`, it's fixed now.