# MEF InheritedExport metadata

Tags: c#, mef

I only have experience with simple usage of MEF. I want to know how best to get the following done.

1. I have an interface class

```
    [InheritedExport]
    public interface IBaseView
    {
    }
```

2. I have multiple implementation classes like following:

```
    [PartCreattionPolicy(PartCreationPolicy.NonShared), ExportMetadata("DisplayName", "SimpleView")
    public class SimpleView : IBaseView
    {
        //Implementation
    }
```

3. Somewhere else, I need to enumerate all the `DisplayName` metadata for all exports present in container. (To show to user). This means I do not want to create the export, but just to inspect its type's metadata.

How do I do this?

Comment: Where is your import?

Comment: @JRLambert : I dont want to import explicitly. Just need to get a list of metadata attributes.

Comment: You still need to import to get the metadata attributes. There is a `Lazy<>` type that you can use that will not create the import until you want to use it.

Comment: @JRLambert : But the `Lazy<>` type means that I can only create a part once. I need multiple instances of the same export.

Comment: You can import it to many places.... and many instances

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked ExportFactory that comes with MEF 2?
It helps creating the export instances dynamically. Refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/17/exportfactory-amp-lt-t-amp-gt-in-mef-2-alok.aspx) msdn article about Exportfactory, And this stack overflow answer on [How to use MEF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11525468/493683).

You can access the metadata from the factory without creating an export.